# Joomla database query SELECT AS

Tags: joomla

So I'm just hypothetically thrilled to be querying my hypothetical database:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'name')));
```

I would, however, like the query to look like:

```
SELECT `user_id` AS `uid`, `name` AS `User-Name`
```

How the heck do I get the AS in there?

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: Since this is specific to Joomla, perhaps this page could be migrated to https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this question is 6 months old, so you've probably found an answer or worked around it, but for anyone else who has a similar problem:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id','name'),array('uid','User-Name')));
```

If you only want to use an alias for some fields, just pass `null` in the array for the fields you don't want to alias, so for example:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id','name'),array(null,'User-Name')));
```

would give

```
"SELECT `user_id`, `name` AS `User-Name`"
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is this:

I create an array with the fields I want to select:

```
$fields = array(
    'a.id'     => 'id',
    'a.field1' => 'field1',
    'a.field2' => 'field2',
    'a.field3' => 'field3',
    'b.field1' => 'bfield1',
    'b.field2' =>  null,
    'b.field3' => 'bfield3',
);
```

In the above array, the keys are used for the db Column names of the query, the values for the aliases, as you can see later in the `$query->select()`.
*When you do not need an alias - just set null.

This helps better to control and check what fields I want and how to name them - and is better for maintenance or changes and is portable enough, as I only have to change my `$fields` array according to my needs.

Then the Joomla select command can be like:

```
$query->select( $db->quoteName(
    array_keys($fields),
    array_values($fields)
));
```

This will produce the following SQL `SELECT` query:

> SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`,`a`.`field1` AS `field1`,`a`.`field2` AS
>   `field2`,`a`.`field3` AS `field3`,`b`.`field1` AS
>   `bfield1`, `field2`, `b`.`field3` AS `bfield3`

Comment: I doubt that you actually need to call `array_values()` here.

Comment: Yes you do need to call `array_values` because `$fields` is different than `array_values($fields)` and it is the `array_values($fields)` what you need to build the query. The above code is tested - but if still in doubt, then just test it and see. And when you do test and have your doubts clear- then consider to upvote my answer if you think it's a helpful and good answer to the OP's question - to help the community use a good solution. @mickmackusa

Comment: Let me ask right back... did you test without calling `array_values()`?  I did not test yet, but `quoteName()` is not concerned about the keys of arrays that are passed as parameters.

Comment: @mickmackusa -thanks for asking... Well, if you study the above code you will see that we feed the `$db->quoteName()` with 2 arrays -  first for the db fields names, second for the aliases. Both of these arrays need to be non-assoc and just contains the corresponding elements. To directly answer your question: Yes, what you said has been tested - that was actually my first attempt - but failed miserably. So given the context of my answer, that attempt to create a readable and easy to maintain solution for a complete select set with aliases, this the way to handle it in the `$db->quoteName()`;)

Comment: I'll need to test this out tomorrow when I get my Joomla computer out.  I don't believe what you are telling me.

Comment: Much to my surprise in the source code ([someone else's repo](https://github.com/Gavakshi/joomla-cms/blob/88ce41a070d06f0b9c559e2a4a5c2493b5943148/libraries/joomla/database/driver.php)), I found: `elseif (is_array($name) && (count($name) == count($as)))
   {
    $count = count($name);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
     $fin[] = $this->quoteName($name[$i], $as[$i]);
    }
   }` this proves your assertion to be right. The two arrays are related by their indexes. I find this to be an strange limitation.  Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('user_id') .' AS '. $db->quoteName('name') .' AS '. $db->quoteName('User-Name'));
```

Be sure to use the full query as described here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

So yours will look something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('user_id') .' AS '. $db->quoteName('name') .' AS '. $db->quoteName('User-Name'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__tablename'));     
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Please note that I havent tested this query using `AS` so let me know if it works or not

Comment: The point here was that I have an array of field names, and I would like to incorporate the AS directly into the array.  Is that sort of thing possible?  It also seems to me that the select you are suggesting would not work.

Comment: `$selects = array('user_id' => 'uid', 'name' => 'User-Name'); foreach ($selects as $name => $alias) { $query->select($db->qn($name) . ' AS ' . $db->qn($alias)); }`

Answer (score 0):

I've got this to work:

```php
->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id`' . ' AS ' . '`uid', 'name`' . ' AS ' . '`User-Name')))
```

Comment: This looks very untidy with the mixture of backticks provided by `quoteName()` and hardcoded backticks.  I would not recommend this purely as a matter of coding style/cleanliness.  I'd say fully use `quoteName()` as documented.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use what [Joomla! suggest us](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

> Note by putting 'a' as a second parameter will generate `#__content` AS `a`

So, you may have something like this:

```
$query
  ->select('*')
  ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
```