# How to assign aliases to an array of column names with Joomla's quoteName()?

Tags: mysql, joomla, alias, backticks

I want to use the AS statement for Aliases in a query.
I use this piece of code:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('NameInQ as nin', 'Name')));
```

Anyway I get this error:

> 'Unknown column 'NameInQ as nin' in 'field list'

`NameInQ` does exist as a column name in the table. `nin` should be the alias.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976625/joomla-database-query-select-as/61209555#61209555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tell Joomla:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('NameInQ as nin', 'Name')));
```

`echo $query->dump();` will tell you:

> ```
> SELECT `NameInQ as nin`,`Name`
> ```

See how it doesn't know how to differentiate an aliased column name from a string with spaces in it?

The Docs: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_quoteName

If you want to assign aliases to column names in Joomla from within the `qn()` / `quoteName()` method, you will need to nominate corresponding aliases for all columns.

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('NameInQ', 'Name'), array('nin', 'Name')));
```

Renders as:

```
SELECT `NameInQ` AS `nin`,`Name` AS `Name`
//     ^-------^----^---^-^----^----^----^-- everything aliased, everything backtick wrapped
```

---

Or, of course you could individualize the `quoteName()` calls, you can avoid aliasing every column.

```
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('NameInQ', 'nin'), $db->quoteName('Name')));
```

Renders as:

> ```
> SELECT `NameInQ` AS `nin`,`Name`
> ```

---

Finally, the truth is: You don't even *need* to quote any of your sample column names because the query will be stable/secure without the extra method call(s). *I recommend leaving them out to minimize query bloat and developer eye-strain.

```
$query->select(array('NameInQ AS nin', 'Name'));
```

or even in raw form:

```
$query->select('NameInQ AS nin, Name');
```

For the record, `Name` (MYSQL is case-insensitive) IS a KEYWORD, but it is not a RESERVED KEYWORD.

See the MySQL Doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-N (there is no "(R)" beside `Name`

Comment: @Claudio If you have Joomla-based questions in the future, please create an account at Joomla StackExchange and ask your questions there.  Not only will you be speaking to a dedicated audience with Joomla-specific expertise, it is possible that a pre-existing page already has the information that you are looking for.